# Flutter Web View Couldn't find constructor 'WebView'

Tags: android, flutter

I'm following [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-webview#0) tutorial, and once I run `flutter run` on project it returns these error messages,

I have tried upgrading flutter SDK and changing Android minSDK version and nothing seems to work.

```
lib/main.dart:25:7: Error: The getter 'WebView' isn't defined for the class '_WebViewAppState'.
 - '_WebViewAppState' is from 'package:webview_in_flutter/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'WebView'.
      WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
      ^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:25:26: Error: The method 'SurfaceAndroidWebView' isn't defined for the class '_WebViewAppState'.
 - '_WebViewAppState' is from 'package:webview_in_flutter/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'SurfaceAndroidWebView'.
      WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:37:19: Error: Couldn't find constructor 'WebView'.
      body: const WebView(
                  ^^^^^^^
```

What's wrong here, this happens for both Android and Web browser debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can get controller from 'onWebViewCreated'

```
class WebViewPage extends StatelessWidget {
   const WebViewPage():super(key: key);

   late WebViewController webController;
   
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    ...
    WebView(
       onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController c) {
          webController = c;
          // use stateful widget and setState here.
       },
       initialUrl: 'your_url',
       // optional (as per you requirement)
       javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
     ),
    ...
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

found solution on: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/117808

```
class _WebViewAppState extends State<WebViewApp> {
          @override
          final controller = WebViewController()
        ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
        ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
         ..setNavigationDelegate(
      NavigationDelegate(
             onProgress: (int progress) {
              // Update loading bar.
             },
         onPageStarted: (String url) {},
            onPageFinished: (String url) {},
             onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
           onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
                if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
                return NavigationDecision.prevent;
           }
               return NavigationDecision.navigate;
              },
            ),
          )
    
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev'));
    
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Flutter WebView'),
          ),
          body: WebViewWidget(controller: controller),
        );
      }
    }
```